# How to get thumbnail such as micro_kind

Tags: android, thumbnails

My code as below:

```
Bitmap getPreview(String path, int THUMBNAIL_SIZE) {
BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bounds);
if((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1)) {
return null;
}

int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight : bounds.outWidth;

BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE;

return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);     
}
```

But this code can only get the same proportion with original one.
I want to get the 96 * 96 such as micro_kind thumbnail, but without using micro_kind.
How can I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the answer by below code:

```
Bitmap sourceBitMap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p, opts);     
sourceBitMap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(sourceBitMap, 96, 96);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Bitmap#createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)?

Example:

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitMap, 96, 96, false)
```

Comment: But this will change proportion.

Comment: I want to change 500 * 250 to 192 * 96. And then cut over scale to 96 * 96.